# How to mark message as unread in go?

Tags: go, imap, flags

I wanna to mark message by IMAP as unread in go. I don't know, what parameters give to "Replace" function. I'm using http://godoc.org/github.com/mxk/go-imap/imap

It's my code:

```
set, _ := imap.NewSeqSet("")
set.AddNum(45364) // 45364 is message's UID
_, err = imap.Wait(c.UIDStore(set, "+FLAGS", imap.Replace()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.2) and the documentation for [Replace](http://godoc.org/github.com/mxk/go-imap/imap#FlagSet.Replace), it looks a bit messy. Investigating the source for Replace, it just wants a []string with the keywords from RFC3501. So, for example

```
flags := []string{}
// ....
_, err = imap.Wait(c.UIDStore(set, "+FLAGS", imap.Replace(flags)))
// Since the "\Seen" is not in splice, the message will be unseen
```

Please notice that Replace really removes all the flags. You have to handle (add to the splice as string values) what you want to preserve:

- \Seen
- \Answered
- \Flagged
- \Deleted
- \Draft
- \Recent

You can get the previous values from the MessageInfo struct / Flags:

```
type MessageInfo struct {
    Attrs        FieldMap  // All returned attributes
    Seq          uint32    // Message sequence number
    UID          uint32    // Unique identifier (optional in non-UID FETCH)
    Flags        FlagSet   // Flags that are set for this message (optional)
    InternalDate time.Time // Internal to the server message timestamp (optional)
    Size         uint32    // Message size in bytes (optional)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way. You can remove the flag. Example:

```
flags := `\Seen`
tmpSet, _ := imap.NewSeqSet("")
tmpSet.AddNum(emailUid)
_, err = imap.Wait(c.UIDStore(tmpSet, "-FLAGS", imap.NewFlagSet(flags)))
```